# Not getting resource file from DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, defaultmodelbinder, app-globalresources

In my MVC3 project, in Global.Application_Start(), I have

```
System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey = "DefaultModelBinder";
```

I also have 2 resource files in App_GlobalResources:

```
DefaultModelBinder.resx
DefaultModelBinder.fr.resx
```

Why isn't the french resource being used at all?

(It is taking the correct value from DefaultModelBinder.resx.)